# How to see number of reads and writes immediately in firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Iam using cloud firebase for a flutter application and at the moment i have to wait for one day to see the detected reads and writes in the console.
Is there a way to see this numbers immediately in the console?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  The console's behavior can't be modified in that way.  This is for performance reasons - having a live view of potentially millions of reads from production users would be taxing on the system and expensive for you, the developer.